# Hiding and showing fields via Javascript based on the type of the category the results item has

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a dynamic list of properties on a search results page, the problem I am having on each individual search result is that if it is a certain property type i.e. Land it does not need the bedrooms and bathrooms fields within that search result to show, but if it is a Villa, the fields would show.

I would need to show and hide fields on the page load in JS like my example above on each individual search result as if I do a general JS function for Land hiding the div classes for bedrooms and bathrooms, there could also be a Villa on the page needing those fields.

If anyone could help with some JS to help me solve this issue above, it would be much appreciated!

Heres some of the Html Results below, you will see there are multiple property types, so different fields should be show/hidden

```
<div class="property-listing">
    <ul>

        <li class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <a href="/propertydetails.aspx?SalePropertyID=615237" class="property-featured-image"><div class="overlay" style="line-height:167px"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
                    <img src="http://example.com/ImageProcessor.aspx?watermarkImageFileName=&amp;Text=NEW LISTING&amp;imageURL=487/Sales/615237/615237_7969.jpg" alt="Villa in Javea">
                    <span class="images-count">
                        <i class="fa fa-link"></i>
                        MidasS
                    </span>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="property-info">
                    <div class="price"><span>115.000</span><strong>€</strong></div>
                    <div class="title">
                        <a href="/propertydetails.aspx?SalePropertyID=615237" title="Villa in Javea">
                            Villa in Javea
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <span class="location"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Alicante, SPAIN</span>
                    <p>A beautiful and rustic style 'home' offering spectacular views over the coast, the mountains and the Mediterranean Sea.</p>
                </div>

                <div class="property-amenities clearfix">
                    <span id="spbeds"><strong>2</strong>Bedrooms</span>
                    <span id="spbaths"><strong>1</strong>Bathrooms</span>
                    <span id="sppool"><strong>Yes</strong>Pool</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <a href="/propertydetails.aspx?SalePropertyID=638700" class="property-featured-image"><div class="overlay" style="line-height:167px"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
                    <img src="http://example.com/ImageProcessor.aspx?watermarkImageFileName=&amp;Text=REDUCED&amp;imageURL=487/Sales/638700/638700_1145.jpg" alt="Apartment in Famagusta">
                    <span class="images-count">
                        <i class="fa fa-link"></i>
                        PRO1011
                    </span>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="property-info">
                    <div class="price"><span>155.000</span><strong>€</strong></div>
                    <div class="title">
                        <a href="/propertydetails.aspx?SalePropertyID=638700" title="Apartment in Famagusta">
                            Apartment in Famagusta
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <span class="location"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Famagusta, CYPRUS</span>
                    <p>hnglkrehnblarjl;kbkhmtr;mnb;rstlmnstrn</p>
                </div>

                <div class="property-amenities clearfix">
                    <span id="spbeds"><strong>0</strong>Bedrooms</span>
                    <span id="spbaths"><strong>0</strong>Bathrooms</span>
                    <span id="sppool"><strong>No</strong>Pool</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <a href="/propertydetails.aspx?SalePropertyID=636364" class="property-featured-image"><div class="overlay" style="line-height:188px"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
                    <img src="http://example.com/487/Sales/636364/636364_5562.jpg" alt="Country House in Not Specified">
                    <span class="images-count">
                        <i class="fa fa-link"></i>
                        cyc130
                    </span>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="property-info">
                    <div class="price"><span>175.000</span><strong>€</strong></div>
                    <div class="title">
                        <a href="/propertydetails.aspx?SalePropertyID=636364" title="Country House in Not Specified">
                            Country House in Not Specified
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <span class="location"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Andalucia, SPAIN</span>
                    <p>;.lkijuhygtfrdeswaq</p>
                </div>

                <div class="property-amenities clearfix">
                    <span id="spbeds"><strong>3</strong>Bedrooms</span>
                    <span id="spbaths"><strong>1</strong>Bathrooms</span>
                    <span id="sppool"><strong>Yes</strong>Pool</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>

        <br> <br>
        <div class="pagination">
            <span class="disabled"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></span>
            <a href="/searchresults.aspx?SearchID=94829-544&amp;Page=1" class="page, active">1</a>
            <a href="/searchresults.aspx?SearchID=94829-544&amp;Page=2" class="page">2</a>
            <a href="/searchresults.aspx?SearchID=94829-544&amp;Page=3" class="page">3</a>
            <a href="/searchresults.aspx?SearchID=94829-544&amp;Page=4" class="page">4</a>
            <a href="/searchresults.aspx?SearchID=94829-544&amp;Page=2" class="next"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You will need to show us some code, at the very least how your HTML and data is structured, ideally what javascript you have so far.

Comment: Please read the Help Center, specifically **[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** and **[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. There's no way anyone can help you with the information provided and we need to know what **you** have done to try and solve your problem.

Comment: please show some code and what you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just gonna go ahead and make up my own HTML structure to demonstrate the simple if/else statement you would make with jQuery.

```js
function hideFields() {

$(".result").each( function() {
  if ( $(this).hasClass("land") ) {
    $(this).children(".bedroom").hide();
    $(this).children(".bathroom").hide();
  }
  else if ( $(this).hasClass("villa") ) {
    $(this).children(".land-area").hide();
  }
});

}

hideFields();
```

```css
span {
display:block;
border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>


<div class="result villa"><b>Villa</b><br>
 <span class="bedroom">Bedroom</span>
 <span class="bathroom">Bathroom</span>
 <span class="location">Location</span>
 <span class="land-area">Land-area</span>
</div>

<br>

<div class="result land"><b>Land</b><br>
 <span class="bedroom">Bedroom</span>
 <span class="bathroom">Bathroom</span>
 <span class="location">Location</span>
 <span class="land-area">Land-area</span>
</div>
```

Your HTML seems confusing for multiple reasons, which you can easily fix to use this method:

1) sppools, spbaths, spbeds should indeed be classes rather than IDs. This is due to IDs being unique identifiers - they should hence not appear more than once on each page, whereas classes identify a "type" (class) of item, which may appear multiple times. Multiple instances of the same ID will mess with your CSS and JS.

2) There is no clear definition within each result of what type of result this is (or I can't seem to find it, at least?).
Words like "villa" or "house" indeed appear in the title-tag, but having to search within these is an inefficient way of performing the action.
Instead, make your code show the type of content as a class on each li-item or the initial div-item.

Comment: I used your example, but had to wrap the hideFields in $(document).ready(function () { }); to get it working, Many thanks Zheer!